# Angular "Show more" button on Infinite Scroll

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

I have been using my own solution for months. I developed it because I thought it is simple. But the code turned out to be quite clumsy and messy. So I gave up, but I can not found any good open source/community base module for that.

I love this one.
https://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

Is there a way to add "show more" button to it ?

Comment: Yes there is, and reading documentation would probably take you less time than posting this question

Comment: @maurycy : I did read the doc, I even used this plugin in my module, can you send me the link to back up your argument ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using outdated documentation, this one is correct https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html and what are you looking for is `infinite-scroll-listen-for-event`

```
<div infinite-scroll-listen-for-event='anEvent'></div>
<button ng-click="broadcastEvent()">Show More</button>
```

and then in controller

```
$scope.broadcastEvent = function () {
  $scope.$broadcast('anEvent')
}
```